# TypeError: invalid destination position for blit (I looked at other solutions to this but they don't work for some reason)

Tags: python, pygame

So I've been trying to make a game and the `TypeError: invalid destination position for blit` error popped up, I have no idea how to solve it.

Here's the problematic code:

```
import pygame, sys
pygame.init()
    
# screen settings
screen_width = 1000
screen_height = 800
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
      """
      player character
      """
      def __init__(self):
          pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
            
          self.x = screen_width / 2
          self.y = screen_height / 2
          self.image = pygame.image.load('img/player.png').convert_alpha()
          self.rect = self.image.get_rect
    
    player = Player()
    player_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
    player_list.add(player)
    
    # game loop
    while True:
    
        for event in pygame.event.get():
    
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                
                sys.exit()
                
        player_list.draw(screen) # traceback thinks this is where the error is
    
        pygame.display.flip()
        pygame.display.update()
```

The code example in here isn't actually the game code, but just the part related to my problem.

I'd appreciate some help.

Comment: It's a typo. You missed the parentheses: `self.rect = self.image.get_rect()`

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code was not the player_list.draw, rather is was the pygame.display.update() messing up your code.

the other problem was the self.rect = self.image.get_rect, it should be self.rect= self.image.get_rect()

and just for future work, you should add an update function to your player class with player_list.update inside your while loop!

#fixed code

```
import pygame, sys
pygame.init()
    
# screen settings
screen_width = 1000
screen_height = 800
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    """player"""
    def __init__(self, window):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.window = window
        self.x = screen_width / 2
        self.y = screen_height / 2
        self.image = pygame.image.load('sprites/NewGumbo.png').convert_alpha()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    
player = Player(screen)
player_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
player_list.add(player)
    
# game loop
while True:
    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
    
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
                
            sys.exit()
                
    player_list.draw(screen) # traceback thinks this is where the error is
    player_list.update()
    
    pygame.display.flip()
```